# What's the word for a counterparty of a customer?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, hypernyms

When I want to refer to the people (and organizations) who supply me with the goods and services I consume---that is, those of whom I am a customer---what word do I use?

My candidates:

- Customee
- Seller
- Supplier

"Customee" gets the meaning across, very effectively I assume, by piggybacking on *-er* and *-ee* being paired in many other contexts.  However, it sounds *awful* (IMNSHO).

"Seller" is less foreign to most ears, but only speaks to what the other party does, not specifically that they do it in relation to me.  Also, and this is probably connected, "my sellers" could easily be mistaken for "the salespeople I have hired" or something similar.

"Supplier" doesn't sound too bad and speaks to what they're doing for me.  However, I have heard  that term used more of suppliers of capital goods---that is, inputs to or tools which facilitate production processes; I haven't heard the term used in reference to those who supply me with consumer goods (the things I want "just because").  For that reason, I think it may sow confusion.

What do?

Comment: Have you searched on synonyms for "supplier" or "retailer" or "vendor"?

Comment: @KristinaLopez: I just did, and got 3*0 hits

Comment: Thesaurus.com does something **really** odd: [supplier](http://thesaurus.com/browse/supplier)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: yep, that had me puzzled as well.

Comment: Hmmm, here's one site for synonyms for "vendor": Synonyms broker, dealer, merchandiser, seller
Related Words merchant, trader, tradesman; auctioneer, concessionaire; black marketer (or black marketeer), bootlegger, fence, fencer, hustler, scalper, smuggler, trafficker; discounter, distributor, e-tailer, exporter, jobber, reseller, retailer, wholesaler; chapman [British], hawker, huckster, peddler (also pedlar); salesclerk, salesman, salesperson, saleswoman, shopgirl; bargainer, haggler, horse trader, palterer

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I'm guessing it does that because it figures ‘supplier’ is a derived form of ‘supply’, which is listed as one of the synonyms of ‘temporary’ (as in ‘supply teacher’). Still a bit odd, though—you'd think ‘supply’ would show up many other and more relevant places than under ‘temporary’!

Comment: @Jan That explains it; except that a *supply teacher* is one who is supplied -- *supply* does not first mean "temporary". It boggles the mind that a "supplier teacher" might be even more short-lived!

Comment: "Customee" does not "bring the meaning across very effectively". I would go so far as to say it brings across *no* meaning whatsoever. In contemporary English, "customer" is no longer interpreted as an agent noun, so the *-er/-ee* path is blocked. You could get away with *buyee*, *sellee*, and even *vendee* before you could get away with *customee*. That's because a buyer buys, a seller sells, and a vendor vends, all pretty transparent and open for morphological games. But a customer does not custom (what does that even mean?), so *-ee* is not productive on that one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: `dict custom`: v. t. 1. to make familiar, to accustom; 2. to supply with customers; v. i. 1. to have a custom. [1913 Webster, via gcide].  I could perhaps get away with vt2, as in "I supply them with customers, viz., me", and thus "customee" will mean "those whom I supply with customers", but if the lingo nerds aren't gonna grok it, no one else will.  Your point stands, but perhaps one step to the _<direction>_.

Answer (score 6):

In my industry, we typically use the term *vendor.*

[Vendor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vendor) - a person or company offering something for sale

When used in *legalese* vendor means "the seller" as opposed to "the buyer."  (Same source as above, see definition 3.)

Answer (score 1):

One possible candidate I stumbled upon while replying to [a comment by RegDwigнt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134432/whats-the-word-for-a-counterparty-of-a-customer?noredirect=1#comment278340_134432):

- Frequentee

In context: "I was just calling up one of my frequentees".  I think (okay, maybe just hope) that it bring across the meaining "I frequent them".  That meaning is still somewhat... dodgy; I frequent their stores rather than them, and that's not always a given (e.g. when I'm buying stuff on the internet).

Still, I think it's better than "Customee", so perhaps we're getting closer.  Along the same lines are "buyee" and "purchasee".  On the other hand---or was that the first hand?---they describe my counterparty in passive terms: they're the ones I'm doing my frequenting, buying, purchasing or customering* *to*; it doesn't say what *they* are doing.

(* yes yes, I know, that's not a word.  Not even a cromulent one.)

Conclusion (for now): I'm still leaning towards suppliers, but it still doesn't sit quite right with me.

Answer (score 1):

**Provider** might be a word. Or service provider. At least this is OK with Internet service.

Answer (score 0):

Some common business words:

- [Supplier](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supplier) is used frequently in business terminology. For example ISO 9001 discusses Supplier Management.
- [Vendor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vendor) is used often for software companies, at least in the USA, as in "software vendor". For example see [NIST's definition](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/Vendor).
- [Provider](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provider?q=Provider) is more often a company that provides services (like an internet connection) instead of products.